# iOS get id of fingerprint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fingerprint

In iOS devices you can add multiple fingers to **Touch ID** in the menu and assign a name to each finger.

When using the fingerprint API, is it possible to get that name or some other ID of the recognized finger on the sensor?

I could not find a solution in the documentation and could imagine that there is none due to some security concept. However, in case I missed something, does someone know a possibility to get an ID of the finger on the sensor? Or does someone know a reliable source stating that this is indeed not possible?

Comment: For security reasons Apple don't allow you to have access to that data. As far as I am aware the only information that you get is if the fingerprint is a match or not.

Comment: This is also what I think, however, I did not find a source verifying this. Do you have a source or are you just guessing like I am?

Comment: See [Local Authentication Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520-CH1). `LAContext` has 2 methods, both of them return true/false or error. I don't think what you want is explicitly stated anywhere, but based on the official documentation it's not possible (although maybe there is some private API that can do this).